# How to post a variable to a php file using ajax

Tags: php, jquery, html, ajax

I want to pass a variable to college.php where that variable can be used to fetch data.

I already tried `get` and `post` methods using form, but then using `get` the variable values are visible in address bar and using get form resubmission alert appears 
this is what I used.

```
<form class="morestories"method="get" enctype="multipart/form-data" action="college.php">

                  <input type="hidden" name="collegename" value="<?php $collegename=$row['name']; echo $collegename; ?>">

                  <input class="morestoriesbutton" type="submit" name="collegeselectlink" value="More Stories" />

                </form>
```

also the variables i am passing to college.php file, on refresh it should be used again to access data so any possible help

Comment: Question is not clear. Can you please specify what exactly are you trying to accomplish here?

Answer (score -1):

This is a example where I am passing name and password to a php function ,
you can refer this and apply it accordingly to your condition.

```
$(document).ready(function(){ 
    //this is my button 
    $("#click").click(function(){  
        // getting username and password from my html
        username = $("#name").val();
        password = $("#pad").val();

        if(username=="" || password==""){
            alert("please check the details");
        } else {
            $.ajax({ url: 'reverse.php',
                data: {username:username,password:password},
                type: 'post',
                success: function(output) {
                     alert(output);
                }
            });
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: in your code u are getting output from ajax request but i want click function to redirect to college.php with the passed variable used there to grab data @shivkumar

Comment: Please look at the url in the ajax.

Comment: specity the funtction name with the url it may help like :

url: 'ABC.php?method=XYZ',